# Django-tables2 Row Selection

Tags: django, django-tables2

How do I select a row from a table generated from django-tables2? I'd prefer not to have to select a row by checking a checkbox cell (`selection = tables.CheckBoxColumn(accessor='pk')`)  in the row.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, you can format the cell as an href, so that the user clicks on it to get the appropriate action- or detail-view. You can accomplish this easily by defining a method on the model to return the appropriate text, including `self.id` or other row-identification from the instance.

Example:

```
class Customer( models.Model):
...
    @property
    def td_inspect(self):
        dest = reverse('customers:detail', args=(self.id,) )
        return format_html('<td><a class="NoUnderline AddWayBack style-inspect" href="{dest}">&#x1f50e;&emsp;</a></td>', dest=dest ) # 1f50e is magnify glass
```

You can also work client-side using JQuery or suchlike, passing the necessary `id` information via something like `<td data_id={id}...`

Comment: In your example, if the user clicks the cell, defined by the td element, the UI will navigate to customers:detail view.  Did I get that correct?  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, assuming that's what the `customers:detail` URL is. The property is on a Customer object.

Comment: I just want to be be able to select the whole row and have that action fire an event so that I can display other data in another view.